# Binding to the scroll wheel then use normal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gsap

I have 2 `div` with height and width of 100%. one is `top:0px` and the other is `top 100%`;

I want to go from one to the other one with an animation which start when I use the mousewheel. it worked fine with my code.

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
   if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
       TweenLite.to(window, 2, {scrollTo:{y:$( "#one").offset().top}});
   } else {  
       TweenLite.to(window, 2, {scrollTo:{y:$("#two").offset().top}});  
   }
}
```

But I want to stop that script when I enter in the second div and then use the wheel as usual for the rest of the page. ( other full pages div)

So I can do

```
....
else {  
    TweenLite.to(window, 2, {scrollTo:{y:$("#two").offset().top}}); 
    $(window).unbind(); (but i dodn't know if it's really ok )
}
```

That works fine. But now I would like to make the wheel script work again when we reach the top of the div "two". I tried with conditions but i couldn't make it work.

This is my code (you can also see it on [this codepen](http://codepen.io/pierre29177/pen/LVgpOb) where it works):

```js
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
  if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
    TweenLite.to(window, 2, {scrollTo:{y:$( "#one").offset().top}, ease:Expo.easeOut});
  }
  else {  
    TweenLite.to(window, 2, {scrollTo:{y:$( "#two").offset().top}, ease:Expo.easeOut});
  }
});
```

```css
body{overflow:hidden}
#one {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background:#733;
}
#two {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background:#439;
}
#three {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 190%;
  z-index: 1;
  background:#896;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

Comment: As a side note: `mousewheel` is a non-standard event and it is deprecated ([see source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel)). You should avoid it on production sites.

Comment: hi.  i had the idea to change it but thanks for your comment about it and the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is not pretty, but it works. You could use it as a workaround while somebody (or yourself or myself) look for a better solution.

```
var animation = false;
var scrollby = 20;

$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
  if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
    if ($( "#two").offset().top == $(window).scrollTop()) {
      TweenLite.to(window, 2, {scrollTo:{y:$( "#one").offset().top}, ease:Expo.easeOut, onComplete:function() { animation=false; }, onStart: function(){ animation=true; } });
    } else {
      if (!animation){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() - scrollby < $( "#two").offset().top) {
          $(window).scrollTop($( "#two").offset().top);
        } else {
          window.scrollBy(0,-scrollby);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else { 
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
      TweenLite.to(window, 2, {scrollTo:{y:$( "#two").offset().top}, ease:Expo.easeOut, onComplete:function() { animation=false; }, onStart: function(){ animation=true; }});
    } else { 
      if (!animation) {window.scrollBy(0,scrollby);}
    }
  }
});
```

You can see it working on [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPewLQ).

Your initial code did this:

- If the mousewheel goes down, scroll down to `#two`.
- If the mousewheel goes up, scroll up to `#one`.

The modified code above changes a bit:

- If the mousewheel goes down:

  - If you are at the top of the page (`#one`), scroll down to `#two`.
  - Or else (you are in `#two` or below), scroll down a given amount.
- If the mousewheel goes up:

  - If you are at `#two`, then scroll up to `#one`.
  - If you are not at `#two` (you are below that point), scroll up a given amount.

I also added a couple of checks to avoid issues:

1. Check if there is an animation (`TweenLite.to`) going on before scrolling. This is achiveved by setting the `animation` variable on the `onStart` and `onComplete` events of TweenLite.
2. If scrolling up you go above `#two`, autocorrect and go to `#two`. This issue only happens when you scroll to the bottom of the page and then scroll up.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, thanks a lot for  you  reply. it works well on chrome but it's not working on firefox v39 But i m gonna work with your solution tomorow and try to improve it. But many thanks for you reply.

Comment: @PierreDebroux Funny thing: It doesn't work on FF because I changed the event to `wheel`, but if I put the original `mousewheel` it works fine for me on FF38. I updated the code accordingly.

Comment: but it's so strange that mozilla says to use wheel event instead of the    mousewheel.  i m gonna check all of this tomorow. And again thanks a lot for the time you give to this.

Comment: for what i see it work also in firefox  when you just used `$(window).bind('DOMMouseScroll', function(event)` and in chrome you need to add  `mousewheel` or `wheel`

Comment: http://codepen.io/pierre29177/pen/LVgpOb     it's working perfect now. i mean if you scroll to the bottom of the page and then scroll up, it's still working. i just set the height of the two last div at 100%.  i m gonna try to make the scroll smoother now. Thanks a lot

Comment: To make them scroll smoother, what you could do is first calculate the target position and then use  `TweenLite.to`. That way the scrolling would be smooth, and probably the code cleaner

Comment: http://codepen.io/pierre29177/pen/LVgpOb does not work for me on Chrome. The one I linked on the answer (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPewLQ) works fine in all the browsers and scrolling to the bottom too

Comment: hey thank you . i don't understand why it works fine in chrome for me on my codepen but thanks. im gonna investigate the smooth scrolling with the TweenMax.